# Let's put [version] in a rocket and send it to the Sun

Tags: support, tags

[version](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/version) seems like a worthless tag. Let's kill it. Ya dig?

Comment: [Set the controls for the heart of the sun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5_0iZQ-TuA)

Answer (score 6):

It fails the "if this is the only tag on a question does it mean anything" test. Which I believe makes it a meta-tag, which we don't like around here.

Burn it.

Comment: Agreed. The dragon will be pleased with this sacrifice.